# Is my proof for the single variable chain rule correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

I have studied the proof for the Chain Rule given by Spivak in *Calculus* but I found the argumentation convoluted, so I tried proving the Chain Rule on my own. I feel like what I've written is watertight but I figured I'd ask here to see if some people stronger than me in math could find any issues with it.

Begin with the statement $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(g(a+h))-f(g(a))}{h}$.

Add and subtract $g(a)$ so that we get:

$=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(g(a)+g(a+h)-g(a))-f(g(a))}{h}$

Assume that the function $g$ is not locally constant. If it is locally constant then by default, $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = 0$. Then, we multiply by $\frac{h}{h}$ inside the function to get:

$=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(g(a)+h\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h})-f(g(a))}{h}$

Then multiply the whole limit expression by $1$ again with $\frac{\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}}{\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}}$:

$=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(g(a)+h\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h})-f(g(a))}{h\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}}\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}$

Since the limit of a product of functions is the product of the limits of each function,

$=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(g(a)+h\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h})-f(g(a))}{h\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}$.

The right hand expression is just $g'(a)$. The left hand expression remains to be evaluated. Here I introduce the secant slope function as well as the derivative:

$\phi(a, h) = \begin{cases} \frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h} & h \neq 0 \\ g'(a) & h = 0\end{cases}$

Substituting,

$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = [\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(g(a)+h\phi(a, h)) - f(g(a))}{h\phi(a,h)}]g'(a)$

Proceed by evaluating the remaining limit expression. Call it $L$, and write a $\delta-\epsilon$ statement of the existence of the limit:

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0: 0<|h|<\delta \implies |\frac{f(g(a)+h\phi(a, h)) - f(g(a))}{h\phi(a,h)} - L|<\epsilon$

We massage the $\delta$ expression by multiplying it by $|\phi(a, h)|$:

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0: 0<|h\phi(a, h)|<\delta|\phi(a, h)| \implies |\frac{f(g(a)+h\phi(a, h)) - f(g(a))}{h\phi(a,h)} - L|<\epsilon$

The point of this was to construct a new $\delta^*$ and allow a substitution to do some cleanup work: $k = h\phi(a, h)$, so that we construct a derivative expression:

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta^*>0: 0<|k|<\delta^* \implies |\frac{f(g(a)+k) - f(g(a))}{k} - L|<\epsilon$

Clearly, $L = f'(g(a))$. So now I can write the chain rule:

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(g(a+h))-f(g(a))}{h} = f'(g(a))g'(a)$. Or,

$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$

I will greatly appreciate any feedback on this!

Comment: If I recall correctly, you have to deal with the possibility that there arbitrarily small $h$ such that $g(a+h) = g(a)$.

Comment: Your proof is largely correct. I am not sure if you are asserting the existence of $L$ before you have proven it; I think you could rewrite it to make it clearer that this is not the case. Indeed, you could just replace $L$ with $f'(g(a))$. There is also a more serious error. It is not justified to make the change of variables $k = h \phi(a,h)$ because, as you have noted, $\phi$ depends on $h$. You will definitely need to use that $\phi$ is continuous at $0$ in some form in order to justify this step.

Comment: How would the continuity of $\phi$ be used, exactly? I realize that $\phi$ could behave in funny ways, so does the continuity of $\phi$ and that $\phi \neq 0$ guarantee that there is some interval on $x$ where $phi$ is nice enough that the change of variables is legal?

Comment: Your proof is not so different from Spivak's one. If you want to see an alternative, you can check Stewart's Calculus, which has a proof that uses (and proves) the fact that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if there exists a real number $L$ and a continuous function $\varepsilon$ such that $f(x)=f(a)+L(x-a)+(x-a)\varepsilon(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}\varepsilon(x)=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: when doing a proof you should be clear on exactly what it is you are proving. The chain rule states that if $g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$, then $f\circ g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $(f\circ g)'(a) = f'(g(a))g'(a)$.

Note that what you know at the start is the differentiability of $f$ and $g$. The differentiability of $f\circ g$ is what you have to prove. In a proof, you start with what you know and derive from that the thing you want to prove.

You simply assume that $f\circ g$ is differentiable at this point:

> $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0: 0<|h|<\delta \implies |\frac{f(g(a)+h\phi(a, h)) - f(g(a))}{h\phi(a,h)} - L|<\epsilon$

The prior limit expression could be considered as conditional on convergence, but at this point, you use this expression to choose the $\delta$ that you need to define $\delta^*$. But that $\delta$ exists only if the limit converges.

As has also been noted, $g(x)$ can equal $g(a)$ infinitely many times near $a$ without $g$ being locally constant. For example, if $a = 0$ and $g(x) = x^2\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$ for $x \ne 0, g(0) =0$. This $g$ is differentiable with $g'(0) = 0$ and is not locally constant. The problem with such cases is that your expression for $\delta^*$ becomes $0$ at those locations, violating the requirement that it be $> 0$.

And again as has been noted, It is $\exists \delta > 0, \forall h$, not $\forall h,\exists \delta^*$. There is no such thing at $h$ when $\delta^*$ is picked.

But on top of all those issues, this whose thing is quixotic, because your conclustion is

> $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta^*>0: 0<|k|<\delta^* \implies
>  |\frac{f(g(a)+k) - f(g(a))}{k} - L|<\epsilon$

i.e., that $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$. So you assumed the thing you were supposed to prove, in order to prove *something you already knew*.

You need to turn it around. Start with the existence of $f'(g(a))$ and $g'(a)$, and deduce the existence of $(f\circ g)'(a)$.

Comment: I should add that since $g$ is differentiable at $a$, it is only possible for $g(x) = g(a)$ at infinitely many places near $a$ if $g'(a) = 0$. This is true because $\frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a}$ will be zero at those locations, so $0$ is the only value the limit can converge to. So you could handle the case $g'(a) = 0$ separately, and then assume $g(x) \ne g(a)$ in some neighborhood of $a$, except at $a$ itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll have a go again with your feedback, but if that doesn't work I think I should just learn Spivak's proof properly, rather than possibly waste many hours of my time attempting to prove a major elementary result from scratch.

Comment: I think a good place to start is to first prove this result: If $\lim_{x\to b} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = b$ and either (1) $f$ is continuous at $b$, or (2) there is a neighborhood of $a$ on which $g \ne b$ except at $a$, then $$\lim_{x \to a} f\circ g(x) = L$$ This is more straight-forward that the chain-rule itself.

Comment: And once you have it, the change rule becomes $$\lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{x - a} = \lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x)- g(a)}\lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}$$ where the second limit is just $g'(a)$ and the first is $f'(g(a))$ by an application of that limit of a composition theorem.

Comment: For the purposes of the chain rule, $f$ needs to be continuous at $g(a)$ for proving the limit of the composition...

Comment: Ok I posted my updated proof as an answer

Comment: I think that your condition (2) isn't quite right. If $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases} -1 & x<0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\ 2 & x>0 \end{cases}$ then the limit of $f(g(x))$ at $0$ doesn't exist. I think that condition (2) should be that $g$ is continuous, so that we can speak of a neighborhood around $g(a)$.

Comment: In addition to the 2 possible conditions, both $f$ and $g$ are required to converge to a limit at the appropriate points. Your $g$ does not converge at $0$, and that is why $f\circ  g$ also does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, following Paul Sinclair's advice, this is how I'd answer my own question (edited 5/3/2023, but shaky about how to use the given that $f$ is continuous at $x=b$):

**Lemma:** If $\lim_{x \to b} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = b$, given that either (1) $f$ is continuous at $b$ or (2) there is a neighborhood of $a$ on which $g \neq b$ except at $x=a$, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = L$.

We have two givens:

(1) $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta'>0: 0 < |y-b| < \delta' \implies |f(y) - L| < \epsilon$, and

(2) $\forall \delta' > 0, \exists \delta>0: 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |g(x) - b| < \delta'$.

If $f$ is continuous at $b$, and given that $\lim_{x \to b}f(x) = L$, then we can conclude that $L = f(b)$. So, if we let $y = g(x)$, then we can merge the two statements:

$0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies 0 < |y - b| < \delta' \implies 0 < |f(y)-f(b)| < \epsilon \implies |f(g(x))-f(b)| < \epsilon$, hence $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x \to a} g(x)) = f(b) = L$.

If there is a neighborhood of $a$ on which $g(x) \neq b$ except at $x=a$, because $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exists and is equal to $b$, $g$ is continuous at $x=a$, hence $b = g(a)$. Let $y = g(x)$.

$0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies 0 < |y - g(a)| < \delta' \implies |f(y)-L| < \epsilon \implies |f(g(x))-L| < \epsilon$, hence $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = L$

**Proving the chain rule:**

Given that $f'(g(a))$ and $g'(a)$ exist, prove that the derivative of $f(g(x))$ at $x=a$ is $f'(g(a))g'(a)$.

Case 1: $g$ is locally constant in a neighborhood of $x=a$. In this case, $g'(a)=0$, which implies $f'(g(a))g'(a)=0$.

Case 2: $g$ is not locally constant in a neighborhood of $x=a$. Here, proceed by rewriting the limit as a limit of a product:

$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{x-a}=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)} \lim_{x \to a}\frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a}$

The second limit evaluates to $g'(a)$. Existence of $g'(a)$ means that $g$ is continuous at $x=a$, so $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)} = \lim_{y \to g(a)}\frac{f(y) - f(g(a))}{y-g(a)} = f'(g(a))$.

Hence, the derivative of $f(g(x))$ at $x=a$ is $f'(g(a))g'(a)$.

Comment: As stated, the lemma is false, and obviously, that means your proof is also not correct. If you go back to my comment, you will see that I very specifically call out two conditions such that one or the other must hold, for the statement to be true. In fact, for full limits where $f$ and $g$ are defined everywhere in neighborhoods of there respective limit points, if both of those conditions are false, $\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x))$ does not converge.

Comment: Just to be clear, even if you are stating the lemma under the conditions of the chain rule (and thus know that $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$), there is still a problem with your proof, which is written as if $f$ were not continuous, and makes no examination of why continuity of $f$ is needful. To see where the problem is, note that the inequality for $|x-b|$ has two sides.

Comment: Your first case for the chain rule itself is also false, $g'(a) = 0$ does not imply anything about the behavior of $f$ itself, which is a completely unrelated function. But even if you correct that to be a statement about $f\circ g$, it still will not be locally constant. If $g'$ were zero on a *neighborhood* of $a$, then $g$ and therefore $f\circ g$ would be locally constant. But all we know is that $g'(a) = 0$, nothing away from $a$. For example, when $f(x) = g(x) = x^2, g'(0) = 0$, yet $f\circ g(x) = x^4$ is not locally constant.

Comment: On the final case, this expression is not well-defined: $\lim_{g(x) \to g(a)}\frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}$, you cannot use it. What you need to do is apply the corrected lemma to $F$ and $g$, where $$F(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{f(x) - f(g(a))}{x - g(a)}& x\ne g(a)\\f'(g(a))&x = g(a)\end{cases}$$ after showing $F$ is continuous.

Comment: Ok. Time to try again. I need to account for the little details.

Comment: Ok, I tried again :)

Comment: in your first case, where $f$ is continuous, we do not know that $y = g(x) \ne b$, so we do not have $0 < |y - b|$ as you claim. This is why we need continuity of $f$, to show that it doesn't matter in this case if $y = b$. When $y \ne b$, the argument you give works. When $y = b$, you need a different argument to show that $|f(y) - L| < \epsilon$. In the other case, we do not know that $g$ is continuous. It does not matter what the value of $g(a)$ is. The limit is about the values when $x \ne a$, not when it is equal to $a$.

Comment: For the chain rule, $g$ being locally constant is not the complete issue. The issue is $g(x) = b$ at some point $x \ne a$. If this happens in every neighborhood $a$, then the difference quotient in the first factor of the product is undefined at points in every neighborhood of $a$. which makes the limit undefined. So you have to handle all the situations in which $g(x) = b$ infinitely many times, not just $g$ being constant. If you make case 1 $g'(a) = 0$, then it covers all these cases, because $g(x) = b$ infinitely many times requires $g'(a) = 0$. Then case 2 is $g'(a) \ne 0$.

Comment: And note: you need to show $(f\circ g)$ is differentiable in both cases and that it is $0$ (not $f'(g(a))g'(a) = 0$) in the first case. And in the second case, $g$ being continuous in not a condition of the lemma. The lemma requires the outside function $F$ to be continuous, not the inside function $g$. But in this case, all you need is the other condition - that $g(x) \ne b$ when $x \ne a$.

Comment: I suppose that a chain rule proof would need to work for a function like $y=x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})$ with infinitely many times it equals zero near the origin. At this point I feel like I'm drowning and so I'm probably better off sticking with learning Spivak's proof.

Comment: That may well be. But I would still suggest learning about why that lemma about composed limits holds, and why the two conditions are necessary. Taking limits of compositions is something that comes up often, and knowing exactly when and why it can be done is useful.

Comment: Yes I agree. The lemma is broader than the theorem presented in Spivak's chapter on continuity, which proves the limit of the composition of two continuous functions, which is a narrower statement.